# Changing the pitch of a threaded hole

Tags: repair

Can I change the pitch of a threaded hole that will accept the diameter of an M6 tap? The current pitch is some off the wall pitch that is not a metric 6 pitch nor the SAE equivalent pitch, the part was made in China.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You're probably going to have to remove more material to make the threads, which means the hole gets larger. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: There are different metric thread pitches, I would get a thread gauge set and measure the pitch and get the correct screw. It’s like national corse and fine 1/4-20 or 1/4-28 both are real values and if you cut new threads with a different pitch there won’t be much left for the screw you want to hold onto.

Comment: What's the use case?  If its for a hammock, failure will cause injury.  Can you get to the backside of the hole?  if so, does your application allow a nut on the far side ?

Comment: M6 seems to only have the single pitch, per thread charts. In SAE, it might be 12-28 rather than 12-24, for instance. Or 1/4-28 rather than 1/4-20, 10-32  rather than 10-24: depending how the M6-1 tap "fits" the threaded hole. I recently had to track down a 1/4-28 setscrew for a hole saw extension - an M6 was a loose fit and there were few enough threads that it did not bind, but it would have ripped out the threads if I really tightened it, so I went to the hardware store...

Comment: iake an impression of the threads using a bamboo skewer and go to a bolt shop. or just take the whole part,

Answer (score 1):

One way is to drill out, re-tap and fit a helicoil to the required thread. Do make sure that this will be strong enough for the purpose.

Of course, it may be possible to find the correct pitch bolts for the original.